# Getting the GET URL through jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to reload part of a page when a form is submitted using `GET` method. The following JavaScript runs, though I am unsure of how to get the submitted URL from the form?

I would have thought `var link = jQuery(this).attr('GET');` or somethign would return it, and have tried `URL` etc... no luck though. Any ideas?

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('GET'); //Get the href attribute
    alert(link);
    history.pushState('data', '', link);
    jQuery('#search_main_section').fadeTo(300,0.3,function(){
        load(link + ' #search_main_section', function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); 
        jQuery('#search_main_section').fadeTo(100,1, function(){}); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var link = jQuery(this).prop('action');
```

And if you want the values of the form, you want to use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Example of using action and searlize with load.

​

```
$("#form1").on("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var action = form.attr("action") || window.location.href;
    var formValues = form.serialize();
    //example with get     
    //$.get(action, formValues, function(){ alert("done"); });
    //example with load
    var url = action + "?" + formValues;
    $.load(url + ' #search_main_section', function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide();
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: and dont forget the return false; at the end!

Comment: `action` only returns the main URL without the GET queries. Any ideas? Will that be through the use of serialize?

Comment: Answered my own question... a combination of `action` and `serialize` is needed, with a question mark between. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="something.php" method="POST">

</form>


jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
   ....// rest of code
```